# Placement of the await operator

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was wondering about the flexibility of the `await` operator in JavaScript. Specifically, how and where can we use it within an expression (inside an `async` function).

e.g.

```
!await Promise.resolve(10);
await !Promise.resolve(10);
```

Which of the above two (or both?) are valid & which is more "conventional"? The expected return value of the expression is `!10`.

For generalising, you can substitute any other kind of expressions / operations in place of the `!`.

Also, is the following valid & appropriate (in terms of programming practices)?

```
for (const i=0; i < await Promise.resolve(10); i++) {...}
```

And is there an in-depth official documentation for this that I can refer to?

Comment: The first one will return `!10` or `false`, the second one will _always_ return `false` since a promise is truthy

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the `await` in the `for` statement while typing it out @StevenTang. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: MDN's documentation of operator precedence could also be helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (const i=0; i < Promise.resolve(10); i++)
```

The value of `Promise.resolve(10)` is a promise, not a number. As a result the comparison of `i < Promise.resolve(x)` will always be false, so will `i > Promise.resolve(x)` because you are comparing with `NaN`.

```js
// all comparisons with NaN are false
console.log(10 < Promise.resolve(1))
console.log(10 > Promise.resolve(1))
console.log(10 == Promise.resolve(1))
console.log(Promise.resolve(1) == Promise.resolve(1))
```

You simply can't use a promise this way outside of an async function. You *could* do this (that's not a recommendation):

```js
async function test(){
    for (let i = 0; i < await Promise.resolve(10); i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
test()
```

Similarly, `!Promise.resolve(10)` will get the result of `not some promise` rather than `not 10`. But awaiting the result works as expected, because then you are comparing a number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, what would you recommend for the `for` loop? Create a separate variable outside (`const forLength = await Promise.resolve(10);`) and use that (`for (let i=0; i < forLength; i++)`)?

Comment: I think it would be clearer to have a variable that is awaited. Something like `count = await somePromise; for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)`, but that's more a matter of opinion. Both will work in an async function, neither will work outside of `await` or `then()`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Promise.resolve(10)` returns a promise that immediately resolves to the value 10.

Secondly, you always need to `await` a promise from inside an `async` function.

So I don't think any of your examples make much sense, aside from maybe `!await Promise.resolve(10);`, assuming you want to essentially do `!10`.

In your for loop example, `for (const i=0; i < Promise.resolve(10); i++) {...}`, what you're doing is comparing a promise to a number, which doesn't make sense. You'd need to await the promise first.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop the expression  **i < Promise.resolve(10)** will always be false because **Promise.resolve(10)** is an object so the loop body will never be executed.